# Free XML Editor for custom XSD

Tags: xml, editor

Our component is configurable using an XML API and we have an XSD that defines this XML-API.

Now, what is the best way our customers could get context sensitive help while creating our XML API? Is there a free tool they could download (or we could distribute) that will take in an XSD and provide context senstive help for the edited XML?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dansharp XML Viewer 
http://www.bizbert.com/xmlviewer
a very simple editor, it takes as input an XML file, and an XSD, and then you can validate to allow the editor to parse the XML and check if there is any errors

Answer (score 0):

[XMLQuire](http://xmlquire.com) is a free, XML Editor for windows that might fit your needs.

This is suitable for passing on to customers, because this is just a 3MB .exe redistributable and doesn't require installation. All the usual XML editing features come as standard.

[image]

XMLQuire comes with a small set of embedded XSD schemas, but your customer can modify a csv file (or you can give them a batch file that does this) that XMLQuire will use to look up namespaces to find an associated top-level XSD file.

Your customer will then get context help for that XSD, starting from the point they enter xmlns="..." in the XML editor, where they're presented with a list of supported namespaces.

Two auto-complete lists are available, one a drop-down popup, the other permanently displayed. The permanently displayed list can display any annotations embedded in your XSD file to provide help text in addition to simply listing expected nodes or values for the context.

*Disclosure: XMLQuire is developed by myself as a personal project.*